# EF Core Migration not working when using `ApplyConfiguration`

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following two classes in my model:

```
public class MyState
{
    private HashSet<MyTransition> _myTransitions;
    private HashSet<MyTransition> _usedBy;
    public MyState()
    {
        _myTransitions = new HashSet<MyTransition>();
        _usedBy = new HashSet<MyTransition>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyTransition> MyTransitions  => _myTransitions?.ToList();
    public IEnumerable<MyTransition> UsedBy => _usedBy?.ToList();
}

public class MyTransition
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public MyState Parent { get; set; }

    public Guid StateId { get; set; }
    public MyState State { get; set; }
}
```

When I create my `DbContext`like this, the `add-migration` command works:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyTransition>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Parent)
            .WithMany(x => x.MyTransitions)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyTransition>()
            .HasOne(x => x.State)
            .WithMany(x => x.UsedBy)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.StateId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyState>().Metadata
            .FindNavigation(nameof(MyState.UsedBy))
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyState>().Metadata
            .FindNavigation(nameof(MyState.MyTransitions))
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}
```

But when I try to move the configuration to separated classes, like this, the `add-migration` command fails:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ItemStateConfig());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TransitionConfig());
    }
}

public class TransitionConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyTransition>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyTransition> entity)
    {
        entity.HasOne(x => x.Parent)
            .WithMany(x => x.MyTransitions)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        entity.HasOne(x => x.State)
            .WithMany(x => x.UsedBy)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.StateId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}



public class ItemStateConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyState>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyState> entity)
    {
        entity.Metadata
            .FindNavigation(nameof(MyState.UsedBy))
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);

        entity.Metadata
            .FindNavigation(nameof(MyState.MyTransitions))
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}
```

The exception thrown is the following:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'property')
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MutablePropertyBaseExtensions.SetPropertyAccessMode(IMutablePropertyBase property, Nullable`1 propertyAccessMode)
>      at WebApplication5.Data.ItemStateConfig.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder`1 entity) in C:\Users\rbasn\source\repos\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\Data\ClassS.cs:line 29
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration[TEntity](IEntityTypeConfiguration`1 configuration)
>      at WebApplication5.Data.ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in C:\Users\rbasn\source\repos\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\Data\ApplicationDbContext.cs:line 21
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>   Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'property')

The two codes should do the exactly same thing, but the 2nd doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't think it's the issue, but I do notice that `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` is in the second `OnModelCreating` (and not the first).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it, but it the behavior is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must apply configuration for `Transition` first, then for `ItemState`.

```
modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TransitionConfig());
modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ItemStateConfig());
```

Otherwise the navigations are not defined yet and `FindNavigation` returns `null`, hence the exception.

That's why it's better to configure the navigation properties at the same place where you configure the relationship, using the `Metadata` property of the relationship builder to get the associated `IMutableForeignKey`, and then `PrincipalToDependent` or `DependentTiProncipal` properties to get the corresponding `IMutableNavigation`.

e.g.

```
public class TransitionConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyTransition>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyTransition> entity)
    {
        entity.HasOne(x => x.Parent)
            .WithMany(x => x.MyTransitions)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .Metadata.PrincipalToDependent // x.MyTransitions
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);

        entity.HasOne(x => x.State)
            .WithMany(x => x.UsedBy)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.StateId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .Metadata.PrincipalToDependent // x.UsedBy
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}
```

In general relationships don't fit well in `IEntityTypeConfiguration` concept because relationship does not belong to any of the involved entity types. For instance, the same relationships can be configured in other entity config:

```
public class ItemStateConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyState>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyTransition> entity)
    {
        entity.HasMany(x => x.MyTransitions)
            .WithOne(x => x.Parent)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .Metadata.PrincipalToDependent // x.MyTransitions
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);

        entity.HasMany(x => x.UsedBy)
            .WithOne(x => x.State)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.StateId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .Metadata.PrincipalToDependent // x.UsedBy
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}
```

Because of that, I prefer configuring relationships directly in `OnModelCreating` rather than in separate `IEntityTypeConfiguration`, thus avoiding "ordering" problems like this.